# Админская часть сайта

Tags: jquery, html, php

Народ! Можете скинуть парочку скришотов или советов как организовать админку для сайта? В плане юзабилити и дизайна. Ответ просто и удобно не жедателен. Побольше конкретики. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

http://www.ourtuts.com/34-outstanding-admin-panels-for-your-web-applications/

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите админ-панель MODX, там все организованно крайне грамотно. Для вдохновения более чем)